# How to write "PDG values" in the header?

Tags: fancyhdr

[image]I want to replace "Symbols" with "PDG Values" in the header. What file do I have to use (for example \listofnomenclature{ll} gives me "Symbols")?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, twoside]{Thesis}  
\graphicspath{Figures/}  


\usepackage[super,square, numbers , comma, sort&compress]{natbib} 
\usepackage{verbatim} 
\usepackage{vector} 
\usepackage{romannum}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{multirow,booktabs}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{epstopdf,amsfonts,epsfig,array,multirow,graphicx,amsmath,amsthm,ltablex,tabularx,setspace,arydshln,amssymb,multirow,enumerate}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\hypersetup{urlcolor=black, citecolor={blue}, linkcolor={blue}, colorlinks=true} 

\begin{document}
\frontmatter     

\clearpage 
\lhead{\emph{PDG Values}} 
\listofnomenclature{ll} 
{
Speed of Light & c = 1 (natural unit) \\
Planck's constant & $\hbar$ = 1 (natural unit) \\
Mass of $D^{*\pm}$ & $M_{D^{*\pm}}$ = 2010.26 $\pm$ 0.05 MeV \\
Mass of $D^{0}$ & $M_{D^{0}}$ = 1864.83 $\pm$ 0.05 MeV \\
Mass of $e$ &  $M_{e}$ = 0.511 MeV \\
Mass of $\mu$ & $M_{\mu}$ =  105.66 MeV \\
Mass of $p$ & $M_{p}$ =  938.27 MeV \\
Mass of $K^{-}$ & $M_{K^{-}}$ = 493.67 $\pm$ 0.016 MeV \\
Mass of $\pi^{+}$ & $M_{\pi^{+}}$ = 139.57 MeV \\
Mass difference of $D{*\pm}$ \& $D^{0}$ & $\Delta$M = 145.4257 $\pm$ 0.0017 MeV \\
BF of $D^{0} \rightarrow K^{-}\pi^{+}$ &  $\mathcal{B}(D^{0} \rightarrow K^{-}\pi^{+})$ = (3.946 $\pm$ 0.030) $\times$ 10$^{-2}$ \\

}


\end{document}
```

Comment: There will be more and better answers if you follow this places standard: a) start code with \documentclass, b) end it with \end{document}, c) make sure it compiles when someone here copies it, d) make sure it still shows your problem. Thank you

Comment: I think the problem is with this line \listofnomenclature{ll}.  This has to be something else.

Comment: Please embed your code snippet as I described a comment ago. This saves us all e.g. from questions about the context of `\lhead` etc. And it saves all of us redoing almost the same amount of typing, just to try and improve your code. Would you please be so kind? Thank you

Comment: I have edited the code in the question. Could you please have a look?

Comment: Thank you, that helps. However, after installing class thesis I see the following problems, where the latter prevents a compile: a) none of the packages listed are needed to compile this excerpt (which often happens), b) because of `\lhead` you probably missed `\usepackage{fancyhdr}` (at least), c) `\listofnomenclature` seems to be a `\(re)newcommand` but it's not defined. // I suggest to add these missing ones AND remove the packages not needed to show your problem. Perhaps it's also useful to add a screenshot to make it self-evident?

Comment: I have again edited the question with the output attached.

Comment: \usepackage{fancyhdr} also doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for adding the screenshot. I doubt anybody can do sth. useful with the (unchanged) code, as it doesn't even compile. To end discussion here, which will soon be highlighted as such, I leave it to other group members now. (That's no offence, just the way this place works.)